# Error when trying to start a Service in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write a service to locate the user by it's GPs location in Android. I wrotre a service for that. But alwasy when I try to start the service the error

`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` appears. I already searched for this problem on google and added the follwoing line to my sourcecode:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

But the Error still appears. What can I do in order to make the service start without any errors? Here is my code:
MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);

        //GPs Standort bestimmung starten
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, Gps_Service.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(intent);

        initButtons();
    }
}
```

"Gps_service.java":

```
public class Gps_Service extends Service implements LocationListener{

    private double längengrad = 0.0, breitengrad = 0.0;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Address adresse;
    String straße, Ort, Land;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 100, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        längengrad = location.getLongitude();
        breitengrad = location.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Comment: Based on the error message mentioning `startActivity` I'm thinking your error might be happening elsewhere in code you aren't showing.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused by starting a Service? Could you show entire stack of an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a service to retreive the user's location via GPS, use Google's [Fused Location API](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

The link provided has a detailed guide about how to implement it and is much more reliable and accurate in receiving location data.

Don't forget this gradle dependency as well:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
```